# Software for Intersection of Ideals in Noncommutative Polynomial algebra

Tags: soft-question, mathematical-software, gap, sage, software

I am looking for software which can compute an intersection of ideals (in particular right ideals) in a noncommutative polynomial algebra and then find its Gröbner Basis.
Most software somehow does not support the intersection of ideals in noncommutative algebras. I have tried Macaulay2, sage, and Gap.

For example in sage:

```
 Q.<x,y>= FreeAlgebra(QQ,2)

sage: I=Q*[x^5]

sage: I

Left Ideal (x^5) of Free Algebra on 2 generators (x, y) over Rational Field

sage: J=Q*[x^4]

sage: I.intersection(J) $\rightarrow $ This should have returned a trivial intersection which is "I" itself.
```

There is a big error ending with

```
AttributeError: 'Ideal_nc' object has no attribute 'intersection'
```

I had asked a similar question in MathStack for Gap which got no answer: [Intersection of Ideal in Gap(QPA)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4845122/intersection-of-ideal-in-gapqpa).

I get a similar thing when I do with Macaulay2. I am in shock that these softwares which are so advanced are somehow devoid of the most basic operation "Intersection". If anyone knows a way kindly share so.

Comment: If the intersection is not finitely generated, what do you want the computer to return?

Comment: There was quite a lof of effort in the CAS Singular to implement various non-commutative rings approximately 10 years ago. Perhaps you find something there? I would start looking for letterplace algorithms.

Comment: Did you try magma? I understand there have been big improvements in non comm groebmer recently.

Comment: @JohnWiltshire-Gordon I was expecting to get Left Ideal generated by so and so generators. Which is what you get for commutative rings.

Comment: @GeordieWilliamson No i didn't...I'll try that aswell then.

Comment: @MarkusLange-Hegermann I'll look into it.. thanks for the comment.